# Does Android 5.0 and later supports TLS v1.0?

Tags: android, ssl

In my app, server has only tls v1.0 enabled
I tried most of solutions like custom SSLSocketFactory, TrustManagers etc.
But i am getting

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
```

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

According to [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Android&version=5.0.0&key=88) Android 5.0  ([and later](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Android&version=7.0&key=139)) supports TLS v1.0. Check whether your server is configured properly using [this tool](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/). 
Maybe you are using a self signed certificate? If so, you need to implement a custom trust manager.

Comment: Thanks.. Any example ?

Comment: Have you checked your server? What was the result? Are you using a self-signed certificate or is there anything else which could lead to java closing the connection (certificate end date is in the past, no certificate at all, weak algorithms...)

Comment: Yes. The result showed the certificate (SHA256withRSA) what next ?

Comment: Could you please provide the whole stacktrace? And are you sure that newer TLS version aren't an option? Would it be an option to use a library like OkHttp? If so, test this:

`OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();`

`okHttpClient.setSocketFactory(new SSLSocketFactoryCompat());`

Comment: No such method setSocketFactory. Also there is no class SSLSocketFactoryCompat.
Also tried using certificatePinnig and adding the hash
Still same issue.

Comment: You are right, I had an outdated documentation. Seems like SSLSocketFactoryCompat was removed. At this point I can't help you anymore. Sorry.